# The LINQ expression could not be translated - rewrite query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Can anyone help me rewrite this query.

Below query to return list of ItemNos (string), even if only few characters match and even if characters match in different place.

For eg: If I pass in "appl" or "apole" or "dpple". I want DB to list "apple".

Code below compiles but returns LINQ expression could not be translated error when run.

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetItemNo(string itemNumber)
     {
         return await itemDbContext.Item                         
                      .Where(p => p.ItemNo.Zip(itemNumber, (c1, c2) => c1 == c2 ? 1 : 0).Sum() >= 4)   
                      .Select(p => p.ItemNo).ToListAsync();

     }
```

Error:

```
'InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Item>() .Where(s => s.ItemNo .Zip( 
second: __itemNumber_0, resultSelector: (c1, c2) => (int)c1 == (int)c2 ? 1 : 0) .Sum() >= 4)' 
could not be translated. 
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation 
explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 
'ToListAsync'. See go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information'.
```

May I know how can I rewrite or rectify this error.

Comment: I would think that the `.Zip()` cannot be translated. If you don't expect too many items in `.Item` you could add a `.ToList()` before the `.Where()` clause. Beware of the fact that the `.ToList()` will resolve all items from the DB and may cause a performance issue.

Comment: Consider using a bog-standard `LIKE` (`EF.Functions.Like`), T-SQL's `DIFFERENCE` (which is not exposed in EF) or else `.Contains()` on some generate subset of your strings. If all else fails, you can put in a user-defined function and call that. None of those solutions is going to perform well in terms of being able to seek an index, though (but they should still be better than retrieving everything, then filtering).

Comment: @Paul Sinnema  You mean like how I have set above? Please see edited code. Then it shows error as 'does not contain definition for 'where' and no accessible extension method'.

Comment: You would need to use `(await ..ToListAsync()).Where()` to make that work.

Comment: No, use `ToList()` not `.ToListAsync()`

Comment: Your suggestion works. Please see modified code above. Thank you both.

Comment: it is not smart to edit the question with the solution ..... No future readers do not see the  **real question**, and might think that what they read is incorrect (because it is in the question)

Comment: I understand, edited back to original question.

Comment: The solution works but takes long time (as mentioned) to iterate and compare as I have like 50000 ItemNos